# Progress bar working but label is not updating

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar, uilabel

I have a library with an Interface.

```
Public Interface Progress
{
    int ProgressValue{get;set;},
    string ProgressText{get;set;},
}
```

Library has a method Create (dummy code):

```
Public Class TestLibrary
{

    Progress _progress;

    Public void Create()
    {
        foreach(var n in TestList)
        {
            // Do Something
            _progress.ProgressValue = GetIndex(n);
            _progress.ProgressText = "Updating..." + n;
        }
    }
}
```

I have a project that references this library and calls Create method. It even Implements Interface Progress.

```
Public Class TestProject : Progress
{
    public int ProgressValue
    {
        get{return progressBar1.Value;}
        set{progressBar1.Value = value;}
    }

    public int ProgressText
    {
        get{return label1.Text;}
        set{label1.Text = value;}
    }
}
```

Now when I run the application, Progress Bar behaves properly and shows the progress correctly, but the Text of label1 does not change at all. But it do change in the end of for loop and shows the last item in loop. Can anyone help me out in this?

Note: All these codes are written directly without testing as I don't have my application now with me. Sorry for any syntax errors.

Comment: Does it change when it's *completed* out of interest? If so, it's probably just a threading issue - it looks like you're doing too much work in your UI thread.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Yes it do change. I edited the question to reflect the same.

Comment: it's surely a threading issue - make sure your "Progress"-Code does not run on the UI thread

Comment: How long does the actual business logic takes? If it takes very less time, then label updation does not reflect in the UI (similar thing i am facing now with backgroundworker). On the other hand, if its taking too long then try giving a break between each iteration of work. As Jon said, do not do on UI thread. Use BackGroundWorker thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Used a `Label instead of ProgressBar`. You can try this code [`using BackGroundWorker`] -

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        private BackgroundWorker _worker;
        BusinessClass _biz = new BusinessClass();
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitWorker();
        }

        private void InitWorker()
        {
            if (_worker != null)
            {
                _worker.Dispose();
            }

            _worker = new BackgroundWorker
            {
                WorkerReportsProgress = true,
                WorkerSupportsCancellation = true
            };
            _worker.DoWork += DoWork;
            _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += RunWorkerCompleted;
            _worker.ProgressChanged += ProgressChanged;
            _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }


        void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            int highestPercentageReached = 0;
            if (_worker.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {
                double i = 0.0d;
                int junk = 0;
                for (i = 0; i <= 199990000; i++)
                {
                    int result = _biz.MyFunction(junk);
                    junk++;

                    // Report progress as a percentage of the total task.
                    var percentComplete = (int)(i / 199990000 * 100);
                    if (percentComplete > highestPercentageReached)
                    {
                        highestPercentageReached = percentComplete;
                        // note I can pass the business class result also and display the same in the LABEL  
                        _worker.ReportProgress(percentComplete, result);
                        _worker.CancelAsync();
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        void RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                // Display some message to the user that task has been
                // cancelled
            }
            else if (e.Error != null)
            {
                // Do something with the error
            }
        }

        void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text =  string.Format("Result {0}: Percent {1}",e.UserState, e.ProgressPercentage);
        }
    }

    public class BusinessClass
    {
        public int MyFunction(int input)
        {
            return input+10;
        }
    }
}
```

Posted the same a few days ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11033200/763026)

Comment: cool... Its a reasonable/standard way to achieve such tasks in Winforms world using backgroundworker.

Answer (score 9):

It sounds like all your work is being done on the UI thread. Don't do that.

Instead, run the loop itself in a background thread, and use `Control.Invoke` or `Control.BeginInvoke` (probably in the `Progress` implementation) to marshal a call across to the UI thread just to update the UI. This will leave your UI responsive (and able to update labels etc) while it's still processing.

Comment: I accepted that answer and I did not have much understanding on these things...After certain amount of experience and knowledge now I can clearly see what you are trying to point out. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted uses one thread. That means every operation is excuted in sequence right after the previous one finished.
Since you can update GUI elements right away, I suppose the code to be run from main thread (a.k.a "GUI thread"). Blocking the GUI thread results in the GUI ("Graphical User Interface") not updating until there is some idle time for it.

Use following example to refresh your label every iteration so that it updates your UI.

```
label1.Text = i.ToString();
label1.Refresh();
```