# Progress bar change the value but not update the graphic

Tags: qt, qprogressbar

I try much method i have find to do this, but no one work for me.

I have tried with qApp.processEvents() and with update() but no one work.

```
void GUI::startLoading(int currentFile) {
    ui->progressBar->setValue(currentFile);
    ui->progressBar->update();
}
```

currentFile is an int of the current loaded file from another function.

[image: debug and build result]

Here's a screenshot of de dubug that told the current value of the progress bar, but the progress bar don't increment.

Comment: Check it [Progress bar not working ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080164/progress-bar-working-but-label-is-not-updating)

Comment: Make sure you are not calling this in a loop. Remember if your member function does not finish the update will never happen.

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing busy work in the GUI thread? Qt needs to get a chance to process events for the redraw to happen.

`update()` only enqueues the redraw. Note that `setValue()` calls `update()` itself. To avoid this problem, you can call `QEventLoop::processEvents()` from time to time (e.g. at the same place where you update the progress bar), or use a worker thread.

Comment: A worker thread is a technical term unrelated to Qt; it describes a thread that is supposed to do heavy lifting in the background. Most modern CPUs have several cores and often a thread is spawned per core. Qt provides several options for offloading background work to other threads so the GUI thread keeps responsive. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html for starters. `QtConcurrent` might be a good framework for you to use.