# How do I set a ProgressBar to increment at each tick of a Timer?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple form that is supposed to start a timer, perform a time-consuming operation, and update a progress bar at a certain interval while that operation is working. Right now, the time-consuming operation is bound to a `SearchButton`. However, nothing happens with the progress bar, even though the time-consuming operation (in this case a download) does take several seconds:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer searchProgressTimer;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.searchProgressTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    }

    private void InitializeTimer()
    {
        this.searchProgressTimer.Interval = 250;
        this.searchProgressTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(searchProgressTimer_Tick);
    }

    void searchProgressTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        searchProgressBar.Increment(1);
        if (searchProgressBar.Value == searchProgressBar.Maximum)
            this.searchProgressTimer.Stop();
    }

    private void SearchDatabase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.searchProgressTimer.Start();

        // Time-consuming operation
        String filename = @"http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/publications/Documents/quarterlybulletin/qb0704.pdf";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(filename), @"file.pdf");
        int test;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 100000; j++)
                test = i + j;


        this.searchProgressTimer.Stop();

    }
}
```

(The functions are named a tad strangely because the actual time-consuming operation is a database search, but that code, although working correctly, is extremely long and involved).

Debugging this code just shows me that the `SearchButton_Click` event handler fires correctly, but the code never jumps to the `searchProgressTimer_Tick` event handler. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any call to InitializeTimer()

Comment: put a breakpoint on `searchProgressBar.Incriment(1)`.  You can do that by clicking in the margin to the left of the line.  A red dot will appear letting you know a breakpoint is there.  Run that in the debugger and see if the breakpoint is hit.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11033200/763026

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So 1) I don't see a call to InitializerTimer() anywhere.

and 2) System.Windows.Forms.Timer raises its tick event on the UI thread.. the very same thread you are doing your time consuming op on.  You will need to yield control to the message pump once in a while in order for the even to be processed.

Comment: Both of those were the problem. I updated my code to include calls to `BackgroundWorker` and its functionality. I plan on accepting your answer, but should I edit my question and *add* the code that does work?

Comment: Adding the working code to the question will let future searchers get the answer more quickly.  Is up to you.

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing here is a little confusing. Assuming you're actually initializing the timer somewhere - I think this is what's happening...

The `Forms.Timer` class runs entirely on the Form's Message Loop so it CAN NOT fire while a function is running on that thread. So although you `Start()` the timer, the `Click()` function is running on the same thread as the timer so the timer can't fire until that function returns. However, before that function returns you `Stop()` the timer again.

Perhaps you want to look at the `Threading.Timer`. Although - ideally the "work" that you're doing - whether it's a database operating or just a silly nested for loop - should be occurring on a different thread so that the GUI's message loop can still process.

If you do spawn a different thread for this, don't forget to invoke any UI changes or changes to UI elements on the main UI thread!

Answer (score 2):

It's because your GUI updates are happening in the same thread as the database operation.  The database operation should be done in a different thread and make calls to the GUI thread informing it of the update.  Take a look at this as it explains it fairly well.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/progressbar

Comment: Your progress bar will NEVER work correctly if you're doing your time-intensive work in the same thread.  The background worker was made for tasks like this.

Answer (score 1):

> Debugging this code just shows me that the SearchButton_Click event handler fires correctly, but the code never jumps to the searchProgressTimer_Tick event handler.

Try moving your `IntializeTimer()` routine to your form's constructor because it looks like your are never wiring up the tick event for the timer:

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  this.searchProgressTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
  this.searchProgressTimer.Interval = 250;
  this.searchProgressTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(searchProgressTimer_Tick);
}
```