# How do I return a list from a BackgroundWorker for use in the next line of code in the UI thread?

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I'm trying to code part of my application that runs a `BackgroundWorker` process that performs a time-consuming operation. In the main thread, a timer updates a progress bar (this is a continuation of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476364/how-do-i-set-a-progressbar-to-increment-at-each-tick-of-a-timer/11476468#11476468)). However, this code display no `MessageBoxes`. Setting a breakpoint on the `foreach (String word in this.words)` line in the `SearchButton_Click` event handler reveals that `this.words` has no values, i.e. `this.words.Count() == 0`.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Timer searchProgressTimer;
    List<String> words;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        words = new List<String>(3);
    }

    private void SearchDatabase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.searchProgressTimer.Start();
        SearchBackgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

        foreach (String word in this.words) // BREAKPOINT HERE
            MessageBox.Show(word);
    }

    private void SearchBackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // Time-consuming operation
        String filename = @"http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/publications/Documents/quarterlybulletin/qb0704.pdf";
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(filename), @"file.pdf");
        List<String> word_result = new List<String> { "word1", "word2", "word3" };
        e.Result = word_result; // e.result is an Object, and word_result is a List.
    }

    private void SearchBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.searchProgressTimer.Stop();
        this.searchProgressBar.Value = 0;
        this.words = (List<String>)e.Result;
    }   
}
```

My guess as to why this occurs is because the `BackgroundWorker` thread isn't finished with its operation before the main UI thread moves on to the `foreach` loop. I think I understand that part. However, since I want to perform the time-consuming operation in a background thread so the progress bar can update its value as said operation runs, then use the result of the `BackgroundWorker` immediately after its finished, how would I do this?

Please edit my title if it doesn't get the point across as well. I wasn't sure how to phrase this.

Comment: Why was some of the `Timer` code removed, but not other parts? The `this.searchProgressTimer.Start();` line is still there, but other parts are not. I understand removing clutter, but shouldn't **all** of it be removed? I didn't want to change my code sample in case I broke something, but will Henk's changes invalidate the code?

Comment: See here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11033200/763026

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do whatever you want to do in that RunWorkerCompleted event:

```
private void SearchBackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    this.searchProgressTimer.Stop();
    this.searchProgressBar.Value = 0;
    this.words = (List<String>)e.Result;

    foreach (String word in this.words) // BREAKPOINT HERE
        MessageBox.Show(word);
}
```

Since you are getting this information from the background worker, the only way you know you have your list is when the worker completes.

Comment: Will this work if I need to update the main UI? I designed this code as a simple example of what I was trying to do, without cluttering it up with all of the main UI code. Should I post a new question or edit this one to include code that needs to update the main UI?

Comment: @RicardoAltamirano Yes.  The background worker fires the completed event and that's when you can update your UI with whatever you want.  Both `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` are UI events.